# Directory listing for error tomcat in eclipse

Tags: javascript

I am facing "**directory listing for**" error tomcat in eclipse while running my project. Kindly anybody can suggest me what to do?

Comment: When are you getting this error?

Comment: please be specific when you're asking a question. provide your actions and exceptions/errors.

Comment: this is the error i am getting while running a javascript in eclipse. the server i am using is apache tomcat.